# Why do timeline review events sometimes show the number of reviews of each type and sometimes don't?

Tags: support, review, timeline

When looking at the timelines of several different questions, I've noticed something strange: on some sites, timeline review events show the number of reviews of each type completed in that review task, and on other sites they don't.

It's probably better explained through screenshots. Sometimes it looks like this:

[image]

and sometimes it looks like this:

[image]

I recently passed the 500 reputation mark over on Arqade, and timeline review events now look like the second screenshot rather than the first, so it seems to be correlated with the Access Review Queues privilege.

What's the purpose behind this? Why don't timelines ever have pictures of waffles?

Answer (score 3):

The lack of waffles in timelines is their only flaw; I am convinced that Jarrod left waffles out intentionally, as an offering to the gods lest the perfection of his work mock them and call down their wrath upon us all.

If you don't have access to review queues on a site, you won't see the outcome of reviews in the timeline. So you get to see how a review was resolved on Arqade now, but won't on sites where you haven't yet earned [this privilege](/help/privileges/access-review-queues). This avoids a potentially expensive query in cases where the reader couldn't reasonably be expected to do much with the information.

Comment: But the page is unlinked...is there any evidence that <500 rep users accessing the timeline are causing an unacceptable load on the server? Also, you might as well indefinitely cache the review result in the timeline right after the review completes (or more accurately, 15 minutes after it completes to take care of users reviewing 15 minutes after the task was completed).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I just noticed this issue with Suggested Edits on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and Triage on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) and also noticed that it was different for other sites (but I didn't make the connection with access to review queues). I think it would be quite useful to see the summary for users without access to review queues. After all they have access to the information if they want by clicking on "Suggested Edit", for example. I notice this is tagged as support but I guess it has never been turned into a feature request.